# Multithread processing of reconds in spring batch Processors

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to pass a list of Records from From Spring batch Reader to Processor or not as below?

```
public MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<argClass>, List<returnClass>>{

     public List<returnClass> process(List<argClass>){
           //Impementation

     }
}
```

All the examples I could see is, there is a single record(not a list of objects) passed to the processor from Reader. Either it could be SingleItemPeekableReader or JDBCCursorItemReader.

Comment: What is an item in your case? In the chunk processing model, the item reader is designed to read a single item and pass it to the processor. If you define an item as a `List<argClass>`, then you need a custom reader that return items of type `List< argClass>`.

Comment: Thats what exactly I do, Having a custom reader(SingleItemPeekableReader delegate) and forms a list and sending it to processor. But I still get empty read request in my reader, where I dont read any data and an emply  list is passed to processor as well which is not expected.